# How to pass only selective props if class has interface type defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

`interface INewProps {
    _param_1: boolean,
    _param_2: boolean
    _param_3: boolean
}`

`class TestClass extends React.Component<INewProps, IState>{
    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {}
    }
    render() {
        return (<Text></Text>)
    }}`

if I call this it works but;

`<TestClass
    _param_1={false}
    _param_2={false}/>`

If I call this it works but my TSLint in editor says

`Property '_param_3' is missing in type '{ _param_1: false; _param_2: false; }' but required in type 'Readonly<INewProps>'.ts(2741)
SideControl.tsx(89, 5): '_param_3' is declared here.`

I need to pass only 2 props , 
Is there any work around for this? Is this correct way i need to follow?

This interface is used by other class for passing 3 props.
So how do I manage to pass props with 2 ? Is that possible without creating a new interface?
Is Patials in type script associated with this?

Comment: Make the property optional? `_param_3?: boolean` Now users of this property will need to make additional checks to ensure that when it is used, it is not `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your parameter optional in your interface like this:

```
interface INewProps {
    _param_1: boolean,
    _param_2: boolean
    _param_3?: boolean
}
```

note the questions mark on the third parameter.

Read more about optional parameters here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties

Comment: These aren't optional parameters. They're optional properties: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties

Comment: You are correct, I have fixed the link to now go to the correct place